# Parallax scrolling when important part of image gets covered at load time

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have an image with position fixed,over which I have a header and I recently added a new horizontal calendar widget. The problem is, the widget now covers a very important part of the image and the client don't want to let go of the parallax effect as well. Also the image is just large enough to cover the screen, hence adding margin or padding is not  going to help since it would give an empty patch at top of the screen on scrolling. Any suggestions to tackle this situation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.parallax {
position: fixed;
height: auto;
width:auto;
max-width:200px;
max-height:200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<header style="position: absolute;z-index:100 ">HEADER NAVIGATION</header>
<div style="position: absolute;z-index:100 "> 
<p>Code covers the hat</p> 
<p>Code covers the hat</p></div>

<img src="img_parallax.jpg" class="parallax">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index:100; padding-top:145px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.

<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
<p>This  is just here to enable scrolling.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code to share? :)

Comment: show some code then someone can suggest you